# Mongodb - Can I use one arbiter for many replica sets?

Tags: mongodb, replication

Simple question, can I reuse one dedicated arbiter machine for many replica sets, or do I need one arbiter machine per replica set. This is significant because in the worst-case scenario I will need one arbiter per shard, which could get expensive.

Thanks

Comment: Arbiters should not be expensive: they are lightweight `mongod` processes that only exist to vote in elections where the configured number of data-bearing members in a replica set would otherwise be even. For a production environment I would recommend **not** using any arbiters where possible. For example: in a three node replica set two data-bearing nodes plus an arbiter creates asymmetric failover. If a data-bearing node fails, there is still a majority for election purposes but there is no longer a second data-bearing node available for data redundancy or acknowledging `w:majority` writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiple arbiters in a single "machine" by having them run on different ports.  Separate replica sets would have separate arbiters.

Comment: Thanks, so should each arbiter point to a different data directory? E.g. `mongod --port 30000 --dbpath /data/arb --replSet rs`

Comment: Right, they'd each have different ports and different dbpath